# QueueStream for Structured Streaming possible?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

With dStreams, from the official documentation:

> Queue of RDDs as a Stream: For testing a Spark Streaming application
>   with test data, one can also create a DStream based on a queue of
>   RDDs, using streamingContext.queueStream(queueOfRDDs). Each RDD pushed
>   into the queue will be treated as a batch of data in the DStream, and
>   processed like a stream.

So, for Structured Streaming, can I or can I not use QueueStream as input?

Not able able to find anything in the Structured Streaming Guide 2.3 or 2.4.

I do note **memoryStream**. This is the way to go? I think so, and if so, why would QueueStream not be an option anymore?

I have converted QueueStreams to Memory Stream as input and it works fine, but is that what is required?

Comment: Can you share the `memoryStream` snippet you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that for Structured Streaming I cannot use QueueStream - as it is a dStream.

Simulating Streaming input with Structured Streaming does work with memoryStream.